# Problema para probar plugin facebook4

Tags: ionic

Estoy probando una aplicacion que tiene el plugin cordova-sqlite-storage por lo que necesito hacer las pruebas desde mi celular, este funciona correctamente pero cuando instalo y trato de probar cordova-plugin-facebook4 ya no lo puedo ejecutar en mi celular, yo utilizo el siguiente comando "ionic cordova run android --livereload" puedo hacer la prueba en el navegador con "ionic serve --lab" pero no puedo ver los datos ya que el plugin sqlite no funciona, configure todo como sale en la web APP_ID y APP_NAME, utilizando la prueba con ionic serve si se loguea y recupero la informacion o sea que la configuracion firebase y en developer facebook esta correcta, ya no se como probar, elimine y volvi a instalar "ionic cordova platform rm(add) android" y el problema continua. Tambien cambie en config.xml "widget id="com.miempresa.Oficios" version="0.0.1""

Comment: agrega el error que tienes. Ingresa los siguientes comandos **ionic info** y **cordova -v** y agregalas a tu publicación

Answer (score 0):

Proba con `ionic cordova build android --prod` o `ionic cordova build android`

Si te dice que necesitas app-scripts ejecuta lo siguiente `npm i @ionic/app-scripts`

Despues volve a ejecutar `ionic cordova build android --prod`, y luego una vez que finalize, abri el proyecto en Android Studio y luego probalo en el cel.